# How to switch the GSM/3G module off?

Tags: battery, gsm

I only use my smartphone (Samsung Galaxy Chat) as a "pocket computer" (with WiFi) and don't use it to make telephone calls (I use a dual-SIM "dumbphone" for this). All the time it shows a cellular network signal indicator and reports that it can make emergency calls. Can I switch it off to save battery?

Some years ago, when I had a Benefon Esc! GSM+GPS phone, I could independently turn its GSM and GPS modules on/off. I wonder if this is possible in modern day smartphones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch your phone to Airplane mode - this will shut down ALL radios. After this, turn on ONLY the WiFi and you'll be able to use it as a WiFi only device.

Comment: That's it (according to the indication) thanks.